# Manga in which the female lead can see into the future, and saves the male lead's mother

Tags: story-identification, manga

I think it's an isekai. The female lead (FL) knew what was going to happen in the future. In one chapter, she begged to accompany her fiancee's family outing which the male lead (ML) thought was annoying but it turns out that she wanted to save the ML's mother. She prepared a rope and used it to secure the carriage's door so it won't open and the guy obsessed with the ML's mother was not able to kill the mother because of this.

Answer (score 2):

This is *[I Was Reincarnated as the Villainess in an Otome Game but the Boys Love Me Anyway!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-was-reincarnated-as-the-villainess-in-an-otome-game-but-the-boys-love-me-anyway)*

> Mystia Aren is the daughter of a noble family who just started at high school. She’s surrounded by a group of adoring classmates and her charming fiancé. Everything seems perfect. Except that this world is actually a dating sim called “Kyun Love”, and she’s destined to become the main character’s evil rival!

It is an isekai; the main character dies and reincarnates in the world of a game, which is why she's aware of the future. She remembers a detail where one of the capture target's mother dies, and throws a tantrum to ensure she will go on the outing with him and his mother.

[image: Tantrum]

And yes, she uses a rope to secure the carriage, provokes him to cause a scene, and lets the guards take care of him.

[image: Rope]

Comment: Found it on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/OtomeIsekai/comments/u51z57/help_me_find_this_manga/) from another request; I don't think it was the same asker though.